# Changing Ionic alert button class dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, event-handling, alert

Is there a way to dynamically add and remove a class from an [Ionic alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) button?

This is how I am adding buttons to Ionic alert -

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Alert title',
  cssClass: 'my-alert-class',
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Button 1', handler: data => { return false; }, cssClass: 'some-class' },
    { text: 'Button 2', handler: data => { return false; }, cssClass: 'some-class' }
  ]
});
```

Notice the `return false` inside `handler`. This prevents the alert from getting closed(which is ok).

So, as the alert is not closed, I want to change CSS properties of that button just to identify which one got clicked.

I have an option of adding/removing event listeners in case if there is no sol

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find any inbuild ways of doing this, I wrote followings to achieve the functionality.

```
const buttonElms: NodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.my-ionic-alert .alert-button-group .alert-button');
// add "click" event listener to each button
for(let index = 0; index < buttonElms.length; index++) {
  buttonElms[index].addEventListener('click', this.selectedButtonHandler);
}

selectedButtonHandler = (event: MouseEvent)=>{
  // handler for clicked button
  let target: any = event.target; // target element
  let siblings: HTMLCollection = target.parentElement.children; // list of all siblings

  for(let index = 0; index < siblings.length; index++){
    siblings[index].classList.remove('selected-button'); // remove selected class from all siblings
  }
  target.classList.add('selected-button'); // add selected class to currently selected item
};
```